# Displacement of water from a vessel with a small aperture

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

I’m looking at study that examines the intake of sugar solutions by rats. (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20298708)

The authors try to attribute a difference in their findings to a difference in the size of the vessel in which the sugar solution was provided. Their argument is basically that, due to the size difference, more force was required to extract the liquid from one vessel than the other. I am suspicious of physics behind their explanation however, but since I study psychology, I figured I might be able to get some further insight from here.

Both vessels are sealed with the same stopper/spout (such as this one http://www.altdesign.com/products/rodent-ivc/stopper-assembly-with-8-5-neoprene-stopper-and-2-5-straight-open-sipper-tube/) Both vessels are filled with the same amount of solution (30 ml). One vessels has a 100 ml capacity while the other has 60 ml. Rats drink by licking the small aperture of the spout which is angled downward into their cage.

Now here is the reasoning provided by the authors:

*"Since the same stopper and drinking spout were used with both the glass cylinders [vessel 1] and plastic syringes [vessel 2] it is possible that the work required to get fluid out of the different tubes may account for the difference in amounts drunk between the groups. Both the 100 ml graduated glass cylinder and the 60 ml modified plastic syringe contained 30 ml of sucrose; therefore, there was 70 ml of air volume in the former and 30 ml of air volume in the latter. As sucrose is drawn out by the rat, the air volume in the cylinder/syringe is briefly expanded; once the rat releases the suction pressure at the tip of the spout, solution in the spout is drawn back up forming an air bubble at the tip. This air bubble then travels up the tube to join the air in the cylinder/syringe. For the 70 ml air volume, removal of a 1 ml drop of solution decreases the pressure by 1 part in 70 or 1.4%. For the 30 ml air volume, removal of a 1 ml drop decreases the pressure by 1 part in 30 or 3.3%. In short, it requires about twice the applied pressure by the rat to remove a given amount of fluid from the 60 ml syringe as it does to remove the same amount from the 100 ml cylinder. One possible explanation for the present results, therefore, is that there may have been a higher response cost in drinking from the modified 60 ml plastic syringe."*

Does this explanation hold water? If not, does anyone have an idea as to how the difference in force required for displacing liquid from such vessels might be estimated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Air may be well modeled by the [ideal gas equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas_law): $pV=nRT$, where $p$ is pressure, $V$ is volume of air, and $T$ is temperature. For constant temperature, you can see that
\begin{align}
pV & = constant \\
\ln p+\ln V & = constant \\
\therefore \frac{\delta p}{p} & =-\frac{\delta V}{V} \\
\textrm{or, } \delta p & ~\alpha -\frac{\delta V}{V^2} \\
\textrm{Work done}~\approx \delta p\delta V~& \alpha~ \left( \frac{\delta V}{V} \right)^2
\end{align}

Therefore for the same change in volume $\delta V$, larger the volume of air $V$, smaller is the work done.